# What algorithms used in audio limiters?

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I'd like to recreate it in `numpy` or other python library.

I mean a function, that not just simply clips all the samples above the threshold level or normalizes the whole audio. But a function that takes an audio waveform in a range `(-1;1)`, attack time, decay time and threshold level in dB. Reduces the volume of samples above the threshold without distortion and outputs a new sound.

All the solutions I've found so far either add distortion like `ffmpeg` or don't use 64-bit floating point calculations like `SOX`.

Comment: Maybe take a look at how something open source with this feature, like Audacity, implements their version? Also this doesn't even sound like a language-specific question if you're not sure yet how you'd implement this from a design standpoint, let alone the specific code.

Comment: It is a good idea with Audacity. I found a `limiter.ny` there, but I don't understand the language. I already did `RMS` and `Peak Normalization` in `numpy`, so `numpy` preferable.

Comment: Unfortunate that that code is in Nyquist format, but at least it's there as an option if you can't find anything else. I'd also recommend posing this question to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, while making sure to follow the rules of that site, as this is more of a general signal processing question than code related.

Comment: fundamental audio format is PCM which is by definition the format used by audio algorithms ... beautiful thing is PCM is just a curve which wobbles from min to max range as defined by the range of integer values ... if unsigned integers vary from 0 to maxint-1 else if signed integers it varies from negative to positive based in bit depth of the PCM format ... for this raw audio in PCM other than bit depth other main variable is sample rate ... so once in PCM you simply alter the points on this raw audio curve to manipulate the audio with total freedom ... can be done using any language